# How to pass the kind for real precision to functions and subroutines in Fortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, data-kinds

I want to make my subroutines and functions in Fortran support both single and double precisions for reals, and other kinds for various variables, the same as intrinsic functions in Fortran. sin(x) would give us a double precision value of the sine function if x is double precision, while a single precision is x is single precision.

I wrote the following test and I declared my constants a64 and b64 and associate them with their kind value (8). I want my function **divide_real** to output a double precision result if the input variables a and b are double and to output a single precision if the inputs are single precision. This is possible by including the rk parameter as an input to the function, but the compiler complaints about rk that is not declared or is a variable which doesn't reduce to a constant expression (GNU compiler).

Any tips on how to have this to work?

```
 program test_kinds
 implicit none
 real(kind=4)    :: a32,b32
 real(kind=8)    :: a64,b64,divide_reals

 a64=atan(0.40)
 b64=atan(0.30)

 a32=a64
 b32=b64

 write(*,*) '32 bits :: ',divide_reals(a32,b32,4)
 write(*,*) '64 bits :: ',divide_reals(a64,b64,8)
 end program test_kinds

function divide_reals(a,b,rk)
implicit none
integer,intent(in)  :: rk
real(kind=rk),intent(in) :: a,b
real(kind=rk)            :: divide_reals

divide_reals=a/b
end function divide_reals
```

Comment: Please note kind=4 and kind=8 is not portable - there is not guarantee that such kinds correspond to real or double precision, or even that they are supported at all